# 404 Error when connecting to multiple sites on the same domain

Tags: iis, dns, haproxy, iis-bindings

We have 2 websites hosted on different web servers at:

https://site1.mydomain.com
https://site2.mydomain.com

These both have DNS entries pointing to the same IP which utilises a HAProxy to manage traffic to load-balanced web servers.

If we go to the first site, then we cannot connect to the second site for 5 minutes. We will get a HTTP Error 404 not found error. If we wait 5 minutes then it connects.

We've tried various changes at the IIS level for settings of AppPools, bindings etc, but cannot see a root cause of this problem. The browsers appear to be caching something for the first site, and using a private browser allows us to access the second, but we need to be able to hit multiple sites.

There are just 2 in this example, but we have 20 sites in total with this issue. All sites have https and SSL Certificates. These are new servers, and we didn't have the same issue on our legacy servers, but we can see no difference in the setup and configuration.

Any ideas of where to start would be helpful, as we can't determine if this is infrastructure, dev or networking where the issue lies.

We have tried many various binding and AppPool settings, changing IPs for the DNS, setting up a new HAProxy server for a new environment, but the same 404 always happens on the second site.

Comment: The second site is instantly accessible using a private browsing window, it's possible your local browser cache is causing the issue. If you try clearing your browser cache and trying to access the website again will it be successful?

Comment: Yes, the local browsers are caching calls, but it's valid that our end clients should be able to hit multiple sites of ours at the same time.

Using a private browser or another browser works, but we can't ask end users to do that

Comment: Without seeing your config it's hard to tell what's going wrong here. First thing you want to find out is: is haproxy throwing the 404 or the backend (webserver) behind it? You should be able to find that out from your logs. Basically if you define seperate frontend and backend sections for your sites in haproxy, you should have no caching problems there at all. What happens in your backend is another matter.

Comment: By the way, what's with the @ in the domain names? You are using the same domain and path but with a different user to distinguish sites or is this just a confusing example?

Answer (score 0):

Please try implementing cache control headers in the web server's response. This will instruct the browser not to cache certain resources or pages. You can add a no-cache header for IIS by placing this web.config in the root of the folder or site where you want to set it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
   <location path="index.html">
     <system.webServer>
       <httpProtocol>
         <customHeaders>
           <add name="Cache-Control" value="no-cache" />
         </customHeaders>
       </httpProtocol>
     </system.webServer>
   </location>
</configuration>
```